# Is Vaishya a dwija caste?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, varnashrama, vaishya

Is Vaishaya a dwija (twice born) caste ? If Vaishayas are dwija (twice born) then why does Gita put them in the same category as that of women and shudras ?

Gita 9:32

> O son of Prtha, those who take shelter in Me, though they be of sinful-womb, women, **vaisyas**  as well as sudras, can approach the supreme destination.

Were Vaishayas put in twice-born category later in the history ?

Answer (score 1):

In view of Swami Madhusudhana Saraswati s commentary on Srimad Bhagavad Gita,

Here in (9.32) it refers to those vaishyas who engage themselves only in trade or agriculture etc, plunging themselves into their materialistic pursuits(thereby there is an absence of study despite being dwija) ,owing to which they are bereft of the knowledge of the path towards the supreme goal.

*Swami Madhusudana Saraswatis Commentary*

> O son of Prthā, *hi*, it is certain; that *vyapāśritya*, by taking
> shelter, *mãm*, under Me; *ye api*, even those, *syuh*, who are; *pâpa-
> yonayah,* born of sin, or the animals
> and birds, who are defiled by lowly birth, so also *striyah*, women,
> who are inferior owing to being absence of study of the Vedas
> etc., *vaisyāh*, **Vaiśyas, who are engaged only in agriculture etc.;**
> *tathā,* as also; *šüdrāh,* Südras, who
> can't attain the Goal because of the absence of study, etc. owing to their birth; *te api,* even they; *yānti*, reach; *parâm,* the highest, gatim, Goal.
> By the word api are meant also the evil-doers mentioned earlier.

---

The above verse is a follow up of the previous(9.30)

> Even if a man of very bad conduct worships Me with onepointed devotion, he is to be considered verily good. For he has resolved rightly.
> (9.30)
> *Translation Swami Gambirananda*

> As fire equally burns all things that come in touch with it, and it
> does not burn anything that remains away; or, as the wish-fulfilling tree
> impartially fulfils the wishes, good or bad, of people living under it, similarly God acts towards people according to their devotion or want of it.
> *Swami Madhusudana Saraswatis Commentary*

In scriptures ,there are anectodes of even worst sinners who had transformed into saints , also women saints etc. who  had attained the supreme goal.( Eg .Brahma Rishi Valmiki, who was originally Ratnakar)